# How to send an automatic email every x days

Tags: php, email, time

I want to send a report from a website to the owner using an email containing the number of total views of the website and the number of views from that week, being that data stored in a .txt file. How can I make my app send an email, lets say... every 7 days? ATM I have the code bellow in my `afterFilter` in my AppController, it was taken from a views counter toturial, and striped of the number->image association, since it displayed the numbers with images. ATM, his should only count the total views.

I am using CakePHP 2.4.4.

**afterFilter**

```
    session_start();
    $counter = $this->webroot."counter.txt";

// Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
    if (!file_exists($counter)) {
        $f = fopen($counter, "w");
        fwrite($f,"0");
        fclose($f);
    }

// Read the current value of our counter file
    $f = fopen($counter,"r");
    $counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter));
    fclose($f);

// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
    if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
        $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
        $counterVal++;
        $f = fopen($counter, "w");
        fwrite($f, $counterVal);
        fclose($f);
    }
    $counterVal = str_pad($counterVal, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

}
```

Comment: Use cron (on Linux) or Windows Task Scheduler (on Windows) to schedule the script to be run as needed.

Comment: This code doesnt look like CakePHP code (or specific to it) at all. You might want to remove the tag for it and stick to PHP tag only since it is not justified. But since you wrongly tagged it as such: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html reading the book helps.

Comment: Can you validate the answer if it's okey ? Your question is still unanswered :/

Comment: @MrMojoRisin Sorry I thought I had already done that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use crontab

http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/cron

> It's an Unix task Scheduler

With cron, you can periodically call a php script for send emails ;)

Example :

```
01 * * * * root echo "This command is run at one min past every hour"
17 8 * * * root echo "This command is run daily at 8:17 am"
17 20 * * * root echo "This command is run daily at 8:17 pm"
00 4 * * 0 root echo "This command is run at 4 am every Sunday"
* 4 * * Sun root echo "So is this"
42 4 1 * * root echo "This command is run 4:42 am every 1st of the month"
01 * 19 07 * root echo "This command is run hourly on the 19th of July"
```